# If a Logos is lost, does it always become a Mythos, and vice-versa?

Tags: city-of-mist

If you lose a Logos card, does that card always become a Mythos, or can you trade a Logos for a Logos? For example, if I lose my Routine: Dead End Job, can I replace it with Routine: Homeless?

Comment: For example, if I lose my Routine: Dead End Job, can I replace it with Routine: Homeless?

Comment: I'd stick that example in the question itself. It wouldn't hurt to have something concrete to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Replacing a theme card switches its polarity when possible.

> The theme you gain is always from the opposite side to the one you lost. If you lost a Mythos theme, you gain a nascent Logos theme; if you lost a Logos theme, you gain a nascent Mythos theme.
>
> --*City of Mist Player's Guide*, "Crisis & Beginning: Replacing a Theme", p.261

I mean, unless you're at 3/1 and the 1 cracks out, fades away, or gets risked and lost as part of one of the big game-changer moves. Then things get weird. But assuming losing this routine wouldn't make you into a being of pure mythos, then yes, you'd bud a mythos theme to replace it. You either blew it out trying to go crazy with your mythos or you cracked your identity in pursuit of a mystery, so a mythos is what replaces it.

### But losing an identity isn't the only way to change it.

> **END OF THE ROAD**
>
> If your Identity ever becomes resolved, rephrase it in the same spirit to describe a new
>   goal, a greater scope, a new angle, etc. Alternatively, if this aspect of your life truly ended, you may replace this Identity’s theme.
>
> --*City of Mist Player's Guide*, "Resolving an Identity", p.253

Resolution is more of a positive step. For example, if you were being driven on by some mission but over the course of play you finally manage to accomplish it, all that fervor doesn't have to just die out. You can find yourself another mission to be dedicated to.

Trying to resolve your daily routine is admittedly a little trickier, especially if what you're thinking about is going from "dead-end job" to "homeless". It's possible to frame that as a positive step, finally being able to get your life together without pointless work for pointless pay eating up your time, maybe leaning on your mythos to survive in a way it couldn't help you before.

But unless you can frame what's happening to you as a positive step you're taking, rather than just cracking something until it breaks, you can't jump straight from one routine to another.

Answer (score 4):

## What the rules say

**Yes, a lost Logos always makes room for a new Mythos, and vice versa; though there are some special procedures for when your last Mythos or Logos is lost.**

See *Player's Guide*, page 261:

> The theme you gain is always from the opposite side to the one you lost. If you lost a Mythos theme, you gain a nascent Logos theme; if you lost a Logos theme, you gain a nascent Mythos theme.
>
> The exception to this rule applies when you lose your last Mythos theme (if you play a Touched character) or last Logos theme (if you play a Legendary character). When you lose your last Mythos theme, you become a Sleeper. When you lose your last Logos theme, you become an Avatar. Read more about these special conditions below.

I won't copy-paste the full sections here, but basically an Avatar (or Sleeper) will still have three Mythos (or Logos) themes and their final fourth theme represents a tenuous connection to an Identity (or Mystery). These are both "climactic" states for your character, with special rules about your abilities and what happens next.

---

## Some notes on why

Okay, so, you may be wondering *why* the game does this (and whether you should change it, perhaps).

If you're hacking the *City of Mist* ruleset to fit your own superheroic or magical setting, this may well be a rule that you end up rewriting to better suit your needs. (For example, I've experimented with making additional Mythoi harder to open up for a *Kult*/*Mage*-style urban-occult campaign.)

In the game's standard setting, though, the theme-swapping constraint serves to emphasize the duality of your characters: there's a *lot* going on in their lives, aspects of Mystery and Identity are always pulling them in different directions. You may well become homeless, in the story, when you lose your `Routine: Dead End Job` after using too many sick days — but now the Mystery of your mythic self is clawing at you even harder than before, and you haven't had time to learn your new "routine" (the actual *skills* of being homeless) yet.

Also, remember that the typical character's Logos is their isn't boring filler. It's all the experiences, relationships, personality traits, and life-defining drives that aren't part of their magical mythic second self. An action/noir protagonist's "regular" life could mean they're a private detective, an investigative reporter, a celebrated lounge singer, a powerful socialite, a daring graffiti artist, or even a not-so-super vigilante.

Think of the CoM characters more like Peter Parker trying to juggle all this *stuff* he's involved with rather than, e.g., Neo awakening from the Matrix — always juggling, always feeling that push-and-pull, firmly planted in two worlds because both worlds matter.